# Как передать информацию?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

Подскажите, у кого какие есть варианты? Необходимо передать разным людям, разную информацию. Я понимаю, что скорее всего нужно делать через firebase авторизацию и относительно ввода данных давать необходимую инфу пользователю. Образно, есть 10-20 или 100 человек, но каждому из них нужно передать свою инфу. Вообщем как то так... Спасибо за любую помощь. Возможно какие то примеры есть.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял вам нужно передавать информацию из откудо-то к пользователям.

Для этого есть 2 варианта решения:

1. сервер(если вам нужно раздавать данные в зависимости от каких-то параметров)
   2)firebase

Создание сервера это не просто но и не сильно сложно. Например на python можно сделать с фреймворком flask за пару дней спокойно.

Если же вы хотите повозиться с firebase тогда вам надо  сделать регистрацию и авторизацию и к тем аккаунтам добавлять данные которые будет читать приложение

Здесь пример как реализовать регистрацию + программно добавлять данные к конкретному аккаунту:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
email=userEmail.getText().toString();
password=UserPassword.getText().toString();

mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(AddUsers.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            AddUserInfo(task.getResult().getUser().getUid());
            Toast.makeText(AddUsers.this, "User is Added", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
});
}

private void AddUserInfo(String id) {
UserClass user=new UserClass();
user.setUserID(id);
user.setUserName(Name);
user.setUserPassword(Password);


mdatabaseReference.child("Users").child(id).setValue(user);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: В двух словах, есть бланк, в него нужно вносить информацию (разную), и раздавать разным пользователям, в зависимости от их потребностей. Возможно ли это с помощью firebase?

Comment: @Андрей Мостовенко это возможно но надо смотреть конкретную задачу с конкретными данными. В общем вам не составит труда найти код чтобы добавить данные в firebase и потом читать их. Вам останется только как-то структурировать эти данные, хоть они и разные.

Comment: спасибо, за ответ. Если можно, вопрос не по теме. Можете объяснить, как добавить google pay в приложение, или что то подобное?